# MS Graph List Calendars only pulls a subset of the calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, powershell-7.0

I'm trying to pull a list of 20 calendars from an account, however when I use the "List Calendars" API call, I am only able to retrieve 14.  After I pull the first 10 calendars then attempted to pull the last 10 using the "@odata.nextLink" I only retrieve 4, and there is no additional link provided.

Any advice on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the count by running the query :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars?$count=true
```

If you have 20 calendars, you should be able to see the value correctly.

Next try to run:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars?$top=20
```

If you still cannot see all the calendars, please get back.

Also please make sure you have the correct permissions required as given in -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions